# How can I delete a big file from a Git repo?

Tags: git

I accidently commited a movie file to a git repo. I tried to publish it and it's so big, it fails to push. If I delete the file, it's still technically in the repo, right? Is there a way to really really get rid of it, so I can push the repo?

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool. its designed for this purpose.

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

[image]